# Java Arraylist from type <Contact> extraction to JTextFied

Tags: java, arraylist, strongly-typed-dataset

I have the below Code in my contact database and I need to learn how to extract that data to multiple appropriate JTextFields for display in the GUI.

```
ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
contacts.add(new Contact("Sally", "Smells", "2535551212", "ssmels@somedomain.edu"));
```

This is what my Contact.class looks like.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>
{  

public Contact [] contacts;
public int contactNum;
public int currentContact;  
public String search;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String phone;
public String eMail;



public Contact() 
{
    super();

}

public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String eMail, String phone) 
{
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.eMail = eMail;
    this.phone = phone;

}

@Override
public int compareTo(Contact o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @return the contacts
 */
public Contact[] getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

/**
 * @param contacts the contacts to set
 */
public void setContacts(Contact[] contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

/**
 * @return the contactNum
 */
public int getContactNum() {
    return contactNum;
}

/**
 * @param contactNum the contactNum to set
 */
public void setContactNum(int contactNum) {
    this.contactNum = contactNum;
}

/**
 * @return the currentContact
 */
public int getCurrentContact() {
    return currentContact;
}

/**
 * @param currentContact the currentContact to set
 */
public void setCurrentContact(int currentContact) {
    this.currentContact = currentContact;
}

/**
 * @return the search
 */
public String getSearch() {
    return search;
}

/**
 * @param search the search to set
 */
public void setSearch(String search) {
    this.search = search;
}

/**
 * @return the firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

/**
 * @param firstName the firstName to set
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

/**
 * @return the lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * @param lastName the lastName to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

/**
 * @return the phone
 */
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

/**
 * @param phone the phone to set
 */
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

/**
 * @return the eMail
 */
public String geteMail() {
    return eMail;
}

/**
 * @param eMail the eMail to set
 */
public void seteMail(String eMail) {
    this.eMail = eMail;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contact [contacts=" + Arrays.toString(contacts)
            + ", contactNum=" + contactNum + ", currentContact="
            + currentContact + ", search=" + search + ", firstName="
            + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", phone=" + phone
            + ", eMail=" + eMail + "]";
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + contactNum;
    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(contacts);
    result = prime * result + currentContact;
    result = prime * result + ((eMail == null) ? 0 : eMail.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((phone == null) ? 0 : phone.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((search == null) ? 0 : search.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Contact))
        return false;
    Contact other = (Contact) obj;
    if (contactNum != other.contactNum)
        return false;
    if (!Arrays.equals(contacts, other.contacts))
        return false;
    if (currentContact != other.currentContact)
        return false;
    if (eMail == null) {
        if (other.eMail != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!eMail.equals(other.eMail))
        return false;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    if (phone == null) {
        if (other.phone != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!phone.equals(other.phone))
        return false;
    if (search == null) {
        if (other.search != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!search.equals(other.search))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

And this is my TestContacts.Java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;


public class TestContact extends JFrame 
{




private JTextField txtFldSearch;
private JTextField txtFld_FirstName;
private JTextField txtFld_LastName;
private JTextField txtFld_Phone;
private JTextField txtFld_eMail;
public enum searchBy { First, Last, Phone, eMail };



private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TestContact frame = new TestContact();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TestContact() {
     ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

     contacts.add(new Contact("Sally", "Smells", "2535551212", "ssmels@anyschool.edu"));
     contacts.add(new Contact("Joe", "Smells", "2535551212", "jsmels@anyschool.edu"));
     contacts.add(new Contact("Ally", "Bally", "2535551212", "aball@anyschool.edu"));
     contacts.add(new Contact("Ah", "chu", "2535551212", "ahchu@anyschool.edu"));
     contacts.add(new Contact("Molly", "Mocks", "2535551212", "mmocks@anyschool.edu"));



    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 393, 192);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    mntmOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            // open data here

        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmOpen);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mntmSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            // save data here
            System.out.println("prentent to save.\n\nSaving..........");

        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            //file exit
            System.out.println("prentent to save.\n\nSaving..........");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);

    JLabel lblSearch = new JLabel("Search: ");
    menuBar.add(lblSearch);

    txtFldSearch = new JTextField();
    txtFldSearch.setToolTipText("Enter search criteria");
    menuBar.add(txtFldSearch);
    txtFldSearch.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblBy = new JLabel("By: ");
    menuBar.add(lblBy);

    JComboBox ddlSearchBy = new JComboBox();

    ddlSearchBy.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {

            searchBy enumval = searchBy.valueOf(arg0.getItem().toString());
            switch (enumval.ordinal() + 1) {
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:



                break;
            case 3:


                break;
            case 4:


                break;
            default:

                break;
            }
        }
    });

    ddlSearchBy.setToolTipText("Search by");
    ddlSearchBy.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"First", "Last", "Phone", "eMail"}));
    menuBar.add(ddlSearchBy);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First name: ");
    lblFirstName.setBounds(6, 20, 100, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblFirstName);

    JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last name: ");
    lblLastName.setBounds(6, 48, 100, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblLastName);

    JLabel lblPhone = new JLabel("Phone: ");
    lblPhone.setBounds(6, 76, 100, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblPhone);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("eMail: ");
    lblEmail.setBounds(6, 104, 100, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    txtFld_FirstName = new JTextField();
    txtFld_FirstName.setToolTipText("First name");
    txtFld_FirstName.setBounds(77, 14, 185, 28);
    contentPane.add(txtFld_FirstName);
    txtFld_FirstName.setColumns(10);

    txtFld_LastName = new JTextField();
    txtFld_LastName.setToolTipText("Last name");
    txtFld_LastName.setBounds(77, 42, 185, 28);
    contentPane.add(txtFld_LastName);
    txtFld_LastName.setColumns(10);

    txtFld_Phone = new JTextField();
    txtFld_Phone.setToolTipText("Phone number");
    txtFld_Phone.setBounds(50, 70, 212, 28);
    contentPane.add(txtFld_Phone);
    txtFld_Phone.setColumns(10);

    txtFld_eMail = new JTextField();
    txtFld_eMail.setToolTipText("eMail address");
    txtFld_eMail.setBounds(50, 98, 212, 28);
    contentPane.add(txtFld_eMail);
    txtFld_eMail.setColumns(10);

    JButton jbtn_fwd = new JButton(">>");
    jbtn_fwd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // fwd index here

        }
    });
    jbtn_fwd.setBounds(274, 71, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(jbtn_fwd);

    JButton jbtn_bak = new JButton("<<");
    jbtn_bak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // Back index here

        }
    });
    jbtn_bak.setBounds(274, 99, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(jbtn_bak);

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

            // add contact

        }
    });
    btnAdd.setBounds(274, 15, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnAdd);

    JButton btnDel = new JButton("Del");
    btnDel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // delete contact
            contacts.remove(index);
        }
    });
    btnDel.setBounds(274, 43, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnDel);

}

/**
 * @return the txtFldSearch
 */
public JTextField getTxtFldSearch() {
    return txtFldSearch;
}

/**
 * @param txtFldSearch the txtFldSearch to set
 */
public void setTxtFldSearch(JTextField txtFldSearch) {
    this.txtFldSearch = txtFldSearch;
}

/**
 * @return the txtFld_FirstName
 */
public JTextField getTxtFld_FirstName() {
    return txtFld_FirstName;
}

/**
 * @param txtFld_FirstName the txtFld_FirstName to set
 */
public void setTxtFld_FirstName(JTextField txtFld_FirstName) {
    this.txtFld_FirstName = txtFld_FirstName;
}

/**
 * @return the txtFld_LastName
 */
public JTextField getTxtFld_LastName() {
    return txtFld_LastName;
}

/**
 * @param txtFld_LastName the txtFld_LastName to set
 */
public void setTxtFld_LastName(JTextField txtFld_LastName) {
    this.txtFld_LastName = txtFld_LastName;
}

/**
 * @return the txtFld_Phone
 */
public JTextField getTxtFld_Phone() {
    return txtFld_Phone;
}

/**
 * @param txtFld_Phone the txtFld_Phone to set
 */
public void setTxtFld_Phone(JTextField txtFld_Phone) {
    this.txtFld_Phone = txtFld_Phone;
}

/**
 * @return the txtFld_eMail
 */
public JTextField getTxtFld_eMail() {
    return txtFld_eMail;
}

/**
 * @param txtFld_eMail the txtFld_eMail to set
 */
public void setTxtFld_eMail(JTextField txtFld_eMail) {
    this.txtFld_eMail = txtFld_eMail;
}

/**
 * @return the buttonGroup
 */
public ButtonGroup getButtonGroup() {
    return buttonGroup;
}

/**
 * @param buttonGroup the buttonGroup to set
 */
public void setButtonGroup(ButtonGroup buttonGroup) {
    this.buttonGroup = buttonGroup;
}

/**
 * @return the contentPane
 */
@Override
public JPanel getContentPane() {
    return contentPane;
}

/**
 * @param contentPane the contentPane to set
 */
public void setContentPane(JPanel contentPane) {
    this.contentPane = contentPane;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestContact [txtFldSearch=" + txtFldSearch
            + ", txtFld_FirstName=" + txtFld_FirstName
            + ", txtFld_LastName=" + txtFld_LastName + ", txtFld_Phone="
            + txtFld_Phone + ", txtFld_eMail=" + txtFld_eMail
            + ", buttonGroup=" + buttonGroup + ", contentPane="
            + contentPane + "]";
}


}
```

Comment: [That's a *lot* of code to get through, and not a lot of us here have the patience/time to go through that for you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/175248)  It would be better to reduce the code slice to a smaller subset of your specific problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I'm having a meal before I get back on this, then i'll ask some more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

For each object of type `Contact`, there must be an accessor to the fields you want with the data type you want.  For instance, `getEmail()` may provide the e-mail address.  Author and use these accessors in populating your `JTextFields`.

Comment: I have getters and setters but, I'm mentally exhausted at the moment and not seeing where all I am screwing up on this assignment.

Comment: @David:  Take a break, then.  You can't do much when you're mentally fatigued.  I did look at your class accessors, and they do appear to be doing way too much.  You have all of the pieces you need to move data from the Contacts object to a JTextField object, though; maybe you need sleep/food?